# Angular form sends empty data

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have problem with sending data to server from my form in angular, i can get user current data from database and show them but i am not able to send data back, instead it sends empty values.

## Screenshots

`playload of sending data to server`

[image: one]

`profile edit page with current data`

[image: two]

## Code

`HTML`

```
<form [formGroup]="userUpdate" (ngSubmit)="update()" *ngIf="user">
    <ion-item class="ion-margin-top">
      <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [value]="user.name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    //rest of the fields
    <ion-button class="ion-margin-top" type="submit" expand="full" color="success" >Update</ion-button>
</form>
```

`profile.page.ts`

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

  public userUpdate: FormGroup;
  imageURI: any;
  user = null;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private camera: Camera,
  ) {
    this.userUpdate = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      avatar: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menu.enable(true);
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.authService.getToken().then(() => {
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/profile');
      }
    });

    this.authService.user().subscribe((user: any) => {
      this.user = user.success;
      console.log('user success', user.success);
    });
  }

  update() {
    const userUpdate = this.userUpdate.value;
    this.authService.update(
      userUpdate.name,
      userUpdate.username,
      userUpdate.email,
      userUpdate.password,
      userUpdate.phone,
      userUpdate.avatar = this.imageURI
      ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(data);
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`profile.service.ts`

```
update(
    name: String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    phone: String,
    avatar: String
    ) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + this.token.success.token
    });
    return this.http.post(this.env.BASE_URL + '/updateUser',
      {
        name: name,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        phone: phone,
        avatar: avatar
      }, { headers: headers }
    );
  }
```

**Any idea why it sends empty data and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set user value using HTML value attribute, Angular reactive form source of control is class so setting value in html does not add the value to formControl instance. Instead you can use setValue or patchValue method if you want to set Value dynamically to input field.

```
  this.authService.user().subscribe((user: any) => {
      this.user = user.success;
      this.userUpdate.patchValue({
            name:user.name,
            username: user.username ,//Assuming user object has username property
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password ,
            phone: user.phone
     });
      console.log('user success', user.success);
    });
```

[For More Info](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value)

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mguych)

Comment: and i remove ``[value]="xxxx"` from html?

Comment: i just tried to make new app to test not see the result yet

Comment: it didn't work, first of all i tried patch without my `[value]` in html and it return nothing, then i made another app with `[value]` and patch function it did show values but this time unlike my first screenshot there was only my image field sent not all of them.

Comment: it loads very slow but ok i try

Comment: no error except from my backend which expect all fields to be fill

Comment: yes i did, also i used your code above which is same as sample using `patchValue`

Comment: I've found the issue, i.e. `name: user.name,` didn't work because my user data are under `user.success` either i should have user `name: this.user.name,` or `name: user.success.name,` to get data in my form.  Thanks

Comment: Sure @Enthu let me check